# How to work with command line arguments in J

Tags: j

In J console mode  if I type ARGV I get the full path of jqt.exe But when I try to pass some strings to a J script file I get 'syntax error' or 'domain error'. How does argument passing and retrieval or display work?

Comment: a=:ARGV echo a not working for me

Comment: If F is a file -> F 'hello' 'world' shows syntax error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to a file you would pass the information using

```
'string' 1:!2 'filepath/jscriptfile'
```

see https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx001.htm

if you want to pass an argument to a verb declared in a script, you would first have to load the script

```
load 'filepath/jscriptfile'
```

Then as long as the script contains verbs that have been assigned using `=:` so that the verb is not local to the script file, you would pass the string to the verb, which has now been loaded.

```
verb 'string'
```

Answer (score 1):

An interaction with a script that just prints out its arguments:

```
$ cat args.ijs
#! /usr/bin/env j
exit echo each ARGV
$ ./args.ijs
j
./args.ijs
$ ./args.ijs 1 2 3
j
./args.ijs
1
2
3
$ ./args.ijs '1 2' 3
j
./args.ijs
1 2
3
```

`ARGV` is a list of the boxed arguments to the script. It works like any list of boxed literals, and if you're a domain error it's from some verb in your script that's given arguments it's not defined to handle. If you're getting a syntax error it's because there's something in your script with incorrect syntax. This is unrelated to `ARGV` as such.

Perhaps you're expecting numerical arguments to be numbers? Arguments are always delivered as strings. Here's a slightly more involved script with usage, that prints the sum of the factorials of its arguments:

```
#! /usr/bin/env j
sumfact =: [: +/ [: ! x:
3 : 0''
  if. (#ARGV) > 2 do.
    echo sumfact > 0&". each 2}.ARGV
    exit 0
  else.
    echo 'usage: ', (1{::ARGV), ' <n1> [<n2> ... <nn>]'
    exit 1
  end.
)
```

As used:

```
$ ./sumfact.ijs
usage: ./sumfact.ijs <n1> [<n2> ... <nn>]
$ ./sumfact.ijs 0
1
$ ./sumfact.ijs 5
120
$ ./sumfact.ijs 5 5 5
360
$ ./sumfact.ijs 100
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

The text after `#!` isn't important; I use `/usr/bin/env j` because I have a `j` in my path that's the usual `bin/jconsole` of a J installation.

Comment: still a bit fuzzy.. How do I call the script? My script is under addons folder.Path is-. C:\Users\...J64-807\addons\argdemo.ijs   1!:1  is for reading file, right? or should I use 0!:1 not sure. 1!:1 < F '1' '2' '3' or just 1 2 3 or something else getting value error or syntax error with whatever I try.

Comment: Hi Bob! Getting string written to my file by following your example. not exactly what I am after, but ok.